# Watir-webdriver hangs fro 1-2 minutes for "repeat" scenario

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have the next method in my page object:

```
def open_random_report(count)
  opened_reports = 0
  rows = self.how_many_reports_present
  cells = self.browser.divs(:class=>/x-grid-cell-inner./)
  type_position = self.calculate_report_type_position
  row_length = 0
  self.browser.divs(:class=>"x-column-header-inner").each do |d|
      if d.visible?
        row_length += 1
      end
  end
  while opened_reports  < count.to_i do
    $start=Time.now
    r = Random.new
    row = r.rand(rows - 2)
    cell_position = type_position + (row * row_length) - 1
    cells[cell_position].a.click
    opened_reports += 1
    sleep 1
    self.close_report
    $finish=Time.now
    p "#{$finish} Report# #{opened_reports} - #{$finish - $start}" 
    f = File.new('log.txt', 'a')
    f.puts "#{$finish} Report# #{opened_reports} - #{$finish - $start}" 
    f.close
  end
  end
```

This code clicks on random cell in the table(table is represented by the extjs-grid) and it works ok except for one thing: from time to time driver hangs for 1-2 minutes. There is no pattern for hanging, it can happens one time during a run or may happen 10 times during the run.
One more detail: When driver click on cell the app generates pdf report that will be shown to the user in preview window. I don't care about the report my goal is just to open reports so I'm closing preview window despite that fact that pdf has already completely loaded or not.
Any ideas why such hanging may happen? Maybe there is some problem with code?

Comment: Have you tried isolating which line is hanging?

Comment: It hangs on this line of code(it happens after report was closed): 
`cells[cell_position].a.click`
But as I said before it happens rather randomly, I can open 100+ reports without hanging at one run and  only 10 at another one. As a workaround I increased the timeouts for watir, so it doesn't crash with TimeoutError at least. But it's rather workaround than a solution.

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with our project and it causes the hangs.